# Finding the square root of a $2\times2$ symmetric matrix using geometry

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, euclidean-geometry

Given a $2\times2$ symmetric matrix;

$A = \left[ \begin{matrix}w^2 & \epsilon \\ \epsilon & k^2 \end{matrix} \right]$

we can define a matrix;

$B = \left[ \begin{matrix}a & b \\ b & c \end{matrix} \right]$

such that $ B*B = A$

By running through the matrix multiplication of $B^2$, its easy to see the relations;

$w^2 = a^2 + b^2 \\ k^2 = c^2 + b^2 \\ \epsilon = (a + c)b $

We can use these equations to describe a triangle of lengths $w$, $k$ and $D$ where $D = (a+c)$. $\epsilon$ is then twice the area of the triangle. $b$ is the height of the perpendicular bisector splitting D into two parts, $a$ and $c$ respectively.

My question then, is if there is a way to write $a$, $b$, and $c$ in terms of $w$, $k$, and $\epsilon$.

Just trying this myself led to algebraic expressions which quickly got out of hand. I was hoping using a geometric approach would simplify things but cant seem to find anything more useful from the construction other than it being an interesting way to represent the equations.

Comment: Note that your choice of diagonal terms only guarantees a nonnegative trace, but if $\epsilon^2> w^2k^2$ then the determinant is negative, so the matrix has a negative eigenvalue, which means it doesn't have a square root. So any solution must somehow constrain $\epsilon$.